# How can I split Openbox `rc.xml` into multiple files?

Tags: files, configuration, openbox, xml

I don't like big text configuration files. So, I would like to split my **`rc.xml`** file into multiple files:

```
rc.xml
rc.keyboard.xml
rc.mouse.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just split it in the files you propose and then just `cat` them all together?

`cat rc-something.xml rc.keyboard.xml rc.mouse.xml > rc.xml`

The only problem is that you will need to `cat` them each time you modify one of the individual files, but that should be trivial..

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way yet :/